# React-select does not submit form on Enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using Formik and React-Select and I would like to submit form on press enter when focussed on select.

When I'm focused on any of other input and press `Enter` it submits form without any problem but when I try to do same with `Select` it does not work. Even in example of formik it does not work. There is any `easy` way to do it? I know that I can listen for `Enter` and submit form, but maybe there is some event or props which should be only attached to `Select`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/73jj9zom96

Comment: how does you determine that user want to submit form ? Suppose your in react-select selected 3 options bt either you can select next option or you cant submit form. Depending on situation you can navigate focus. You can focus to submit on tab press

Answer (score 2):

Their API says there is an “onKeyDown” prop: https://react-select.com/props

Comment: As I wrote `There is any easy way to do it? I know that I can listen for Enter and submit form` - I know that there is `onKeyDown`, but it will need what I wrote - listen for Enter, and submit form. But if there is no other way - yes it'is solution

Comment: You don’t have to create an event listener, you pass a function into “onKeyDown” (that has one argument, e) that says “if e.key === enter, submit form”

Comment: Yes I know, but it's not so simple to pass submit form function into `Select` (levels of nestled component).
I mean that I need to find somehow form and submit it. But well as I see there is no other solution